# Showing a loading div during a jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Im trying to show a loading div while waiting for an ajax call to complete. I have tried a couple of methods but cant seem to get anything to work consistently.

with my current code it works if i have a break point on the function that shows the div once the ajax is complete.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0y8z9u7m/1/)

```js
var https = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/';

function HideCheckShowLoading(checkId) {
    $("#check_" + checkId).hide('slow', function() {
        $("#loading_" + checkId).show('slow');
    });
};

function HideLoadingShowCheck(checkId) {
    $("#loading_" + checkId).finish().hide('slow', function() {
        $("#check_" + checkId).finish().show('slow');
    });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#get').click(function() {
        HideCheckShowLoading(1);
        $.ajax({
            url: https,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response) {
                //do something
            },
            error: function() {
                //do something else                
            }
        }).done(function() {
            HideLoadingShowCheck(1)
        });

    });
    $('#get2').click(function() {
        HideLoadingShowCheck(1);
    });

});
```

```css
#check_1
 {
    background-color:red;
}

#loading_1
 {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="check_1">Check</div>
<div hidden id="loading_1">LOADING</div>
<button id="get">Get</button>
<button id="get2">Get2</button>
```

What i would like to happen is,

1. on the click of a button we hide the check div
2. we show the loading div
3. make the ajax call
4. if successful do something(Reload the contents of the check div)
5. hide the loading div
6. show the check div

As said I have tried a few methods that i have found but i repeatedly get stuck with just the loading div shown

Thanks

Comment: Close, just change `.done(HideLoadingShowCheck());` to `.done(HideLoadingShowCheck);`  (without the extra `()`)

Comment: Look at `beforeSend`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you may be slightly over-complicating things here. Something simple like this would suffice:

```
$('#get').click(function() {
    HideCheckShowLoading();
    $.ajax({
       url: https,
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       type: "GET",
       success: function (response) {
           //do something
       },
       error: function() {
           //do something else                
       },
       complete: HideLoadingShowCheck
   });
});
```

If you don't want the `HideLoadingShowCheck` routine to happen after `success` or `error` (standard behavior of `complete`), you can just move a function call `HideLoadingShowCheck();` into your `success` and `error` blocks instead of using `complete`.

Comment: Hi, This is similar to how i started however doing it this way I am left with the loading div showing and the check div hidden.

Comment: Note that my function call in the complete does not have `()`. As freedomn-m states in his answer, this may be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion but im still left stuck on the loading div. I believe the `complete: function(){HideLoadingShowCheck(1);}` is starting to run before the loading div has finished showing.

Comment: Is your ajax call definitely working? No errors in console? Otherwise, in `HideLoadingShowCheck`, make your first line `$("#loading, #check").finish();` - This will complete the current animation.

Comment: Using your expertise i have almost got it working as i would like it to. I have had to change the order of HideLoadingShowCheck so that it now does the show first.

Answer (score 2):

When you add `()` to a function name, it calls it immediately and returns the result.   What you want to do is pass the function itself, not the result of the function - and you do that without the `()`.

There's no need for the `$.when` (assuming HideCheckShowLoading() doesn't make an ajax call, the jquery animations work differently), and `$.ajax` returns the promise itself, so you can update your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#get').click(function() {
        HideCheckShowLoading();
        $.ajax({
           url: https,
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           type: "GET",
           success: function (response) {
               //do something
           },
           error: function() {
               //do something else                
           }
        }) 
        //.done(HideLoadingShowCheck);
        .done(function() { HideLoadingShowCheck(otherparams); })
    });
});
```

I would change the showcheck function to add `.finish()` incase it's still animating from the showhide:

```
function HideLoadingShowCheck() {
    $("#loading").finish().hide('slow',function () {
        $("#check").finish().show('slow');
    });
};
```

Comment: The example i have provided is simplified, i need to pass in an identifier to the function e.g. `HideLoadingShowCheck(checkId)`

Comment: I have an updated fiddle with your changes and im still stuck on loading, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0y8z9u7m/2/)

Comment: You need to use an anonymous inline function so that the execution is deferred - I've updated the code to show this.

Comment: In your fiddle, you're not receiving `checkId` in HideLoadingShowCheck()

Comment: whoops, still doesnt seem to work. if i put an alert in the `done()` it never gets hit.

Comment: Look in console, your https was giving a 404.  You should be able to change to a fiddle url (maybe /echo/json?)